# Handling big JSONs in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to use ADF for the following scenario:

- a JSON is uploaded to a Azure Storage Blob, containing an array of similar objects
- this JSON is read by ADF with a Lookup Activity and uploaded via a Web Activity to an external sink

I cannot use the Copy Activity, because I need to create a JSON payload for the Web Activity, so I have to lookup the array and paste it like this (payload of the Web Activity):

```
{
   "some field": "value",
   "some more fields": "value",
   ...
   "items": @{activity('GetJsonLookupActivity').output.value}
}
```

The Lookup activity has a known limitation of an upper limit of 5000 rows at a time. If the JSON is larger, only 5000 top rows will be read and all else will be ignored.

I know this, so I have a system that chops payloads into chunks of 5000 rows before uploading to storage. But I'm not the only user, so there's a valid concern that someone else will try uploading bigger files and the pipeline will silently pass with a partial upload, while the user would obviously expect all rows to be uploaded.

I've come up with two concepts for a workaround, but I don't see how to implement either:

1. Is there any way for me to check if the JSON file is too large and fail the pipeline if so? The Lookup Activity doesn't seem to allow row counting, and the Get Metadata Activity only returns the size in bytes.
2. Alternatively, the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#limitations-and-workarounds) propose a workaround of copying data in a foreach loop. But I cannot figure out how I'd use Lookup to first get rows 1-5000 and then 5001-10000 etc. from a JSON. It's easy enough with SQL using `OFFSET N FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY`, but how to do it with a JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set any index range(`1-5,000,5,000-10,000`) when you use LookUp Activity.The workaround mentioned in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity#limitations-and-workarounds) doesn't means you could use LookUp Activity with  pagination,in my opinion.

My workaround is writing an azure function to get the total length of json array before data transfer.Inside azure function,divide the data into different sub temporary files with pagination like `sub1.json,sub2.json...`.Then output an array contains file names.

Grab the array with ForEach Activity, execute lookup activity in the loop. The file path could be set as dynamic value.Then do next Web Activity.

Surely,my idea could be improved.For example,you get the total length of json array and it is under 5000 limitation,you could just return `{"NeedIterate":false}`.Evaluate that response by `IfCondition` Activity to decide which way should be next.It the value is false,execute the LookUp activity directly.All can be divided in the branches.

Comment: So your answer would be that I cannot do that purely in ADF, I need an Azure Function?

Comment: @V0ldek Sorry for the late response.Yeah,that's what i mean exactly.